# Move product to cart Android

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I writing android app, and I need help with one problem.

Goal:

- Add to Cart by tapping button with all of attributes

I have product, parsing from API(JSON)

Code:

```
 string url2 = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
        JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url2);


        ParseAndDisplay1(json);
        ParseAndDisplay2(json);
        ParseAndDisplay3(json);
        ParseAndDisplay4(json);
        ParseAndDisplay5(json);
        ParseAndDisplay6(json);
        ParseAndDisplay7(json);
        ParseAndDisplay8(json);


 private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                //dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonDoc[15].ToString);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

                //string path =  System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                //string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");
                //using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                //{
                //  streamWriter.Write(jsonDoc.ToString());
                //  streamWriter.Close();


                //}
                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue json)
    {



        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);
        productname.Click += delegate {
            var intent404 = new Intent (this, typeof(SoupesDetailActivity1));

            StartActivity (intent404);
        };

            JsonValue firstitem = json [81];

            productname.Text = firstitem ["post_title"];
            price.Text = firstitem ["price"] + " грн";
            weight.Text = firstitem ["weight"] + "г";




    }
```

And I have layout in design which display fields(productname, price,weight)

Axml code:

```html
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="147.6dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout13">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/sushi"
                    android:layout_width="123.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:background="#000" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
                    android:background="#cf8632" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="184.9dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="181.9dp"
                        android:layout_height="63.3dp"
                        android:id="@+id/posttittle"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7.7dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:clickable="true" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="93.8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout16">
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="48.7dp"
                            android:id="@+id/price"
                            android:layout_marginTop="39.8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5.5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="58.8dp"
                            android:layout_height="53.3dp"
                            android:id="@+id/weight"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="41.9dp"
                            android:textColor="#faaf56"
                            android:paddingTop="7dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageButton
                    android:src="@drawable/cart2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="57.1dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                    android:layout_marginTop="34.8dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2.4dp" />
```

I need to generate this in new activity (CartActivity and move product attributes).
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these attributes through intent  as in

```
productname.Click += delegate {
            var intent404 = new Intent (this, typeof(SoupesDetailActivity1));
              JsonValue firstitem = json [81];

            intent404.putStringExtra("title",firstitem ["post_title"]);
            intent404.putStringExtra("price",firstitem ["price"] + " грн");
            intent404.putStringExtra("weight",firstitem ["weight"] + "г");
            StartActivity (intent404);
        };
```

At Receiving Activity

```
String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

Comment: same as you did in your first activity,create an xml under drawable->layout folder and refer it in setContentView of your new activity

Comment: I know this. I talk about block for product.

When I click button, attributes pass to new activity and block generates automatically

Can i do this or no?